# Hide buttons on top form bar

Tags: c#, winforms

Greetings,

I have a simple winform application of which I want to remove the minimize, maximize and close buttons but I want to keep the top bar so people can keep moving the application.

I've been searching for some hooks to do this but sadly I havn't found anything yet.
Does anyone know if this is possible ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply set `ControlBox` to false:

```
ControlBox = false;
```

Make sure your form still has a title so that the title bar shows in full.

Comment: No problem, in my first WinForms days I had the same issue!

Answer (score 0):

Set the ControlBox Property for the window to false.